# GIt: pull specific files by default?

Tags: git

I checked out the search, but none of the questions seem to (clearly) answer this question:

I check out a repo for a latex template (for a dissertation report), and I want to keep my local changes (ie, the report), but pull updates to the rake build file and style sheets. Is there any easy way to make git only pull these files? Perhaps using .gitignore?

Not sure if that's clear or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pull only specific files. An oft-used alternative to what you're trying to do is to stash your current changes, then pull, and then apply the stash:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

This will save the changes you've made and then reapply them after you pull. Note that if the files you changed were also changed by the pull, it's possible there will be merge conflicts that will need to be resolved after applying the stash.

Comment: Ah, okay, that sounds like it covers what I'm trying to do! many thanks.